# R CMD check with R-devel: note occurs about 'https://doi.org/...' address inside \href{} in Rd files

Tags: r, r-package, cran

#### Summary

With R-devel, an `R CMD check` note appears about `\href{https://doi.org/...}{label}` in Rd files. Can this be resolved - i.e. using `\doi{}` ?? - or should an issue be posted about this?

#### Problem

From the R CMD check results in https://github.com/florisvdh/n2khab-fork/runs/1821504203?check_suite_focus=true#step:9:40 :

```
Found the following URLs which should use \doi (with the DOI name only):
  File ‘read_GRTSmh.Rd’:
    https://doi.org/10.5281/zenodo.2611233
    https://doi.org/10.5281/zenodo.3354403
  File ‘read_GRTSmh_base4frac.Rd’:
    https://doi.org/10.5281/zenodo.3354401
  File ‘read_GRTSmh_diffres.Rd’:
    https://doi.org/10.5281/zenodo.3354405
  File ‘read_habitatmap_stdized.Rd’:
    https://doi.org/10.5281/zenodo.3355192
  File ‘read_habitatmap_terr.Rd’:
    https://doi.org/10.5281/zenodo.3468948
  File ‘read_habitatquarries.Rd’:
    https://doi.org/10.5281/zenodo.4072967
  File ‘read_habitatsprings.Rd’:
    https://doi.org/10.5281/zenodo.3550994
  File ‘read_soilmap.Rd’:
    https://doi.org/10.5281/zenodo.3732903
  File ‘read_watersurfaces_hab.Rd’:
    https://doi.org/10.5281/zenodo.3374645
```

I had already shortened this list before, by replacing `\url{https://doi.org/...}` occurrences by `\doi{...}`.

The above remaining cases however concern a DOI address **inside `\href{}`**:

```sh
$ find . -type f -name "*.R" -exec grep -nH "{https://doi.org/" {} --colour \;
./R/GRTSmh.R:232:#' \href{https://doi.org/10.5281/zenodo.2611233}{Zenodo}, is a monolayered GeoTIFF
./R/GRTSmh.R:263:#' \href{https://doi.org/10.5281/zenodo.3354403}{Zenodo}, and can only be
./R/GRTSmh.R:374:#' \href{https://doi.org/10.5281/zenodo.3354401}{Zenodo}.
./R/GRTSmh.R:485:#' at \href{https://doi.org/10.5281/zenodo.3354405}{Zenodo}), composed of
./R/read_habitatdata.R:24:#' \href{https://doi.org/10.5281/zenodo.3355192}{Zenodo}, that
./R/read_habitatdata.R:196:#' \href{https://doi.org/10.5281/zenodo.3374645}{Zenodo}, that contains:
./R/read_habitatdata.R:748:#' \href{https://doi.org/10.5281/zenodo.3468948}{Zenodo}, that contains:
./R/read_habitatdata.R:1079:#' \href{https://doi.org/10.5281/zenodo.3550994}{Zenodo}.
./R/read_habitatdata.R:1276:#' \href{https://doi.org/10.5281/zenodo.4072967}{Zenodo}, that contains:
./R/read_soilmap.R:25:#' \href{https://doi.org/10.5281/zenodo.3732903}{Zenodo}.
```

Can this be solved as well (while retaining the `\href{}{}` behaviour), or is this to be seen as buggy behaviour from the '\doi note'?